VSCode Ruby get message "press 'Enter' to confirm your input or 'Escape to cancel" when run or debug a file
I have actually resolved the problem but passing info for anyone else getting same problem.  Found several solutions but they were answers to symptoms not this problem.
Had created a couple of new projects and each exhibited the same problem.  When run or debug
it would display press 'Enter' to confirm your input or 'Escape to cancel.  Old projects still ran fine.
Found it only happened when used following section of the launch json (not by file name):
{
   "type": "rdbg",
   "name": "Current file",
   "request": "launch",
   "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
   "script": "${file}",
   "askParameters": true
} 

Problem resolved by changing  "askParameters": true to false or removing the line completely from the launch file.
I normally create new projects by copying the vscode folder from a previous project and modifying to suite my purpose.
Found I had several projects with "askParameters": true but they also had the line "args": [] which apparently provided the required parameters.
Do not know how I managed to get a vscode file with "askParameters": true and not "args": [] but this was the problem.
Resolved as specified above

If you would like to ask and answer your own question, that's totally fine but I would recommend doing so in the format of this forum. Ask a well written question that fully describes the problem you were facing with all the necessary debugging details and then write a fully formed answer to the question posed. This provides a value add to the site and maintains consistency with its intent and content format. Right now people will see this as a question with no answers and pass it right by.
